# How to replace Specific URL and replace with Html text using Jquery expression?

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-selectors, javascript-framework

Hello I want to replace Website Link with some Html text.

I want to replace Link with specific word 
for eq. I have facebook URL as below
**http://www.facebook.com/chitralekha.in**

I want to replace this `http://www.facebook.com/` URL with 
 `<a href='http://www.facebook.com/chitralekha.in'> chitralekha.in </a>` in every place in Html page.

I have facebook label with facebook Link

```
<label id="lblfacebook">www.facebook.com/chitralekha.in</label>
```

I want it replace with  
`<label id="lblfacebook"> <a href='www.facebook.com/chitralekha.in'> chitralekha.in</a></label>`

my website URL is fixed for example. **http://www.facebook.com** or **http://facebook.com**.

How can achieve it using Jquery regular expression.?

Comment: Please can you explain yourself more so we can all understand? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're after: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/DATSu/)

```
var re = new RegExp("(http:\/\/(?:www\.)?facebook.com)","gi");
$("body").html($("body").html().replace(re, "<a href='$1/chitralekha.in'> chitralekha.in </a>"));
```

And for grabbing the username too: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/wXvUc/)

Comment: Thanks @Town, Can we do "Chitralekha.in" dynamic after facebook link  Can I get username dynamic replace with fixed "chitralekha.in"  in above example

Comment: @Abhishek: You mean you want to start with `www.facebook.com/username` rather than just www.facebook.com ?

Comment: @Abhishek: Yes, see the update to my answer.  You'll have to change the `[^<]*` part to match with what you're expecting in your string - this looks for anything that isn't a `<`.

Comment: @Town I want like this If URL  www.facebook.com/abcd I want result lik <a href='facebook.com/abcd'; target='_blank'> abcd </a>.. in this case  Username is "abcd" so It should be dynamic. please gave me soultion.

Comment: @Abhishek: That's what the update already does! [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/wXvUc/)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Town its very good example. many thanks to you.. good job... Thanks yaar

Comment: Hello @Town are you doing job/Business ?

Comment: @Abhishek: I was having lunch at the time actually! Although yes, I do have a job... :)

Comment: @Town Thanks.. I also do same. I am from India. nice to meet you.

Comment: @Abhishek: Nice to meet you too :)

Comment: @Town one more question about regular expression if user enter only URL "www.facebook.com/username.one" then it does not work. how I can do it.. "http://" or "www" or Both then give a link to facebook url as given in http://jsfiddle.net/Town/wXvUc/ link..

Comment: @Abhishek: [This should do it](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/xx6zC/).  For testing regular expressions, I use [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm).

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with a regular expression. 
You look for the text that you want to replace and you do it.

Comment: i'm not a genious in regexp, but you can filter literal characters like this: \bTEXT\b

Comment: Thanks @Erick for suggestion. I trying regular expression.. in my Html tag <label id='lblfacebook'>www.facebook.com/chitralekha.in</label> I trying replace with <label id='lblfacebook'><a href='www.facebook.com/chitralekha.in' >chitralekha.in</a></label>..

Comment: @Eric Frick: You can edit your answer rather than posting multiple answers.

Comment: how can i add an comment to a post?

Comment: @Eric Frick: You can either click the 'edit' link below your answer to change it, or if you want to add a comment then just keep doing what you've done here ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#selector").filter(function(){
 return this.value.match(\bhttp://www.facebook.com/\b)
});
```